# What is more "Pythonic" - dict comprehsion with list generator, or an explicit for loop?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function with input 'raw_data'
raw_data consists of lines such as:

```
key1: str1  
key2: str2  
...
```

Where strx is of the form aa:bb:cc:dd... - that is a ':' separated string
There is a helper function which does something to the strings, converting them to values, let's call it `get_value()`

What would be the most pythonic way to return a dict?

```
to_dict(raw_data):
  list_data = raw_data.splitlines()
  return { key.replace(':',''): get_value(str) for key,str in (line.split() for line in list_data)}
```

or

```
to_dict(raw_data):
  list_data = raw_data.splitlines()
  mydict = {}
  for line in list_data:
    key,str = line.split()
    key = key.replace(':', '')
    mydict.update({ key: get_value(str)})
  return mydict
```

Or is there some much more pythonic way of doing this?
I'm aware this might seem opinion based question, but there seems to be a consensus about what is 'more pythonic' or 'less pythonic' way  of doing things, I just don't know what the consensus is in this case.

Comment: the dictionary case is the pythonic way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first expression is more "Pythonic".  If you're worried about readablity, you can take the generator expression out onto its own line.

```
def to_dict(raw_data):
    data = (line.split(': ', 1) for line in raw_data.splitlines())
    return {key: get_value(st) for key, st in data}
```

`line.split(': ', 1)` will split line on only the first `": "`, so `"a: b: c"` becomes `['a', 'b: c']`

Comment: dict should be key: value, but otherwise this answer works great for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
{k:v for l in raw_data.splitlines() for (k,v) in [l.split(":")]}
```

Comment: You have your loops backwards.  They execute from left to right.

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to mention the strings have ':'s in them, updated the question to reflect this

Comment: Thanks Patrick, yes you're quite right - have edited to correct accordingly - I also noticed I had to wrap the `l.split(":")` component in list brackets to avoid the `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` error I was getting when trying to fill (k,v) from the split contents. I'll confess, I'm not entirely sure why that's necessary, but it looks as though it is in this case.

Answer (score 0):

List Comprehension is really a handy and faster way to write for loops in Python in just a single line of code. The idea of comprehension is not just unique to lists in Python. Dictionaries, one of the commonly used data structures in data science, can also do comprehension. This is called dict comprehension or dictionary comprehension.

Remember that, in python a list is defined with square brackets [] and a dictionary is defined with curly braces {}. The same idea is carried over in defining dict comprehension as well. dict comprehension is defined with a similar syntax, but with a key:value pair in expression.